# Looking To Place Related Post Title In Separate <div> In Order To Overlay Image

Tags: php

I am using the code below to show related posts on my blog. I've also included the html output. The code result shows two post images side by side with the title of each post below the image. I would like to put the Title in a separate div so I can overlay the image with it. Thanks for any help.

```
function child_related_posts() {

if ( is_single ( ) ) {

    global $post;

    $count = 0;
    $postIDs = array( $post->ID );
    $related = '';
    $tags = wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID );
    $cats = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID );

    if ( $tags ) {

        foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {

            $tagID[] = $tag->term_id;

        }

        $args = array(
            'tag__in'               => $tagID,
            'post__not_in'          => $postIDs,
            'showposts'             => 2,
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
            'tax_query'             => array(
                array(
                                    'taxonomy'  => 'post_format',
                                    'field'     => 'slug',
                                    'terms'     => array( 
                                        'post-format-link', 
                                        'post-format-status', 
                                        'post-format-aside', 
                                        'post-format-quote'
                                        ),
                                    'operator'  => 'NOT IN'
                )
            )
        );

        $tag_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $tag_query->have_posts() ) {

            while ( $tag_query->have_posts() ) {

                $tag_query->the_post();

                $img = genesis_get_image() ? genesis_get_image( array( 'size' => 'related' ) ) : '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/related.png" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" />';

                $related .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to' . get_the_title() . '">' . $img . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';

                $postIDs[] = $post->ID;

                $count++;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $count <= 4 ) {

        $catIDs = array( );

        foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {

            if ( 3 == $cat )
                continue;
            $catIDs[] = $cat;

        }

        $showposts = 2 - $count;

        $args = array(
            'category__in'          => $catIDs,
            'post__not_in'          => $postIDs,
            'showposts'             => $showposts,
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
            'orderby'               => 'rand',
            'tax_query'             => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy'  => 'post_format',
                                    'field'     => 'slug',
                                    'terms'     => array( 
                                        'post-format-link', 
                                        'post-format-status', 
                                        'post-format-aside', 
                                        'post-format-quote' ),
                                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                                )
            )
        );

        $cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) {

            while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) {

                $cat_query->the_post();

                $img = genesis_get_image() ? genesis_get_image( array( 'size' => 'related' ) ) : '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/related.png" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" />';

                $related .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to' . get_the_title() . '">' . $img . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $related ) {

        printf( '<div class="related-posts"><h3 class="related-title"></h3><ul class="related-list">%s</ul></div>', $related );

    }

    wp_reset_query();

}
```

}

Html Output

```
<ul class="related-list"><li><a href="http://aaaa.com/url/" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link toURL"><img width="375" height="230" src="http://aaaa.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/URL.jpg" class="attachment-related" alt="url-1">Title To Be Place In Separate Container</a></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have created a code snippet in jsfiddle to achieve your requirement.

```
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k9816j0y/

$related .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to' . get_the_title() . '">' . $img . '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span></a></li>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. My question is how do I add <span></span> to the php code so it shows up in the html like your code snippet. I'm assuming I need to edit this line in the code.    $related .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to' . get_the_title() . '">' . $img . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';

Comment: Worked Perfectly! Thanks... Samir

Comment: Please like my post so that others find it useful :)